# ajax request 'Access Control Allow Origin'

Tags: ajax, http-headers, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain, crossdomain-request.js

I am facing a issue of cross origins. I have googled and found some solutions but they are not working in this case. I wonder why.

I am hosting my application in apache tomcat server. And On the application side I am using XMLHttpRequest for request but I am getting "XMLHttpRequest cannot load `http://localhost:8888/systeminfo`. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin '`http://localhost:8080`' is therefore not allowed access."

Here is the Application js file

```
function testget()
{
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
    }
    alert('Getting data');
    xhr.open('GET', 'http://localhost:8888/systeminfo', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','GET');

    xhr.send();
}
```

I am running node js server on local_host:8888 and sending json response when accessed url like '`http://localhost:8888/systeminfo`' .

And here is the json response that I am forming and sending from server

```
function GetSystemInfo(express)
{
    express.namespace('/systeminfo', function(){
        express.get('/', function(req, res){
            var SYSTEM_INFO = 1;
            var jsonres = '{\"event\" : [{ \"apiID\" : \"{0}\" }],\"data\":[{ \"manufacturerName\" : \"MNAME\",\"serialNo\" : \"123456\",}] }'.format(SYSTEM_INFO);
            res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
            res.send(jsonres);
            res.end();
        });
    });

}
```

Please Help.

Regards,

Techtotie.